# How to install Mysql 8.0 unattended?

Tags: mysql, debian

I have a bash installation script that automatically installs mysql without any prompts.

```
wget -c https://dev.mysql.com/get/mysql-apt-config_0.8.16-1_all.deb
sudo dpkg -i mysql-apt-config_0.8.16-1_all.deb
sudo apt update
sudo apt install -y mysql-server
sudo systemctl start mysql.service
sudo systemctl enable mysql.service
```

Afterwards I would like the following to secure the installation:

```
SECURE_MYSQL=$(expect -c "
set timeout 10
spawn mysql_secure_installation
expect \"Would you like to setup VALIDATE PASSWORD plugin?\"
send \"n\r\"
expect \"New password:\"
send \"$DB_ROOT_PASSWORD\r\"
expect \"Re-enter new password:\"
send \"$DB_ROOT_PASSWORD\r\"
expect \"Remove anonymous users?\"
send \"y\r\"
expect \"Disallow root login remotely?\"
send \"y\r\"
expect \"Remove test database and access to it?\"
send \"y\r\"
expect \"Reload privilege tables now?\"
send \"y\r\"
expect eof
")
echo "$SECURE_MYSQL"
```

Something seems to have changed in the latest Debian Buster 10.9.
The moment I install `sudo apt install -y mysql-server` it is asking me for a root password.
And later it breaks when trying to run `mysql_secure_installation`, because root password was already set.

How can I make the installation interactive without any prompts, please?

The [documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql-apt-repo-quick-guide/en/#apt-repo-fresh-install) says:

> Make sure you remember the root password you set. Users who want to
> set a password later can leave the password field blank in the
> dialogue box and just press Ok; in that case, root access to the
> server will be authenticated by Socket Peer-Credential Pluggable
> Authentication for connections using a Unix socket file. You can set
> the root password later using the program mysql_secure_installation.

How can I leave the password as blank upon installation?

Answer (score 4):

I found the solution.  The issue is that the environment variable `DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive` isn't passed on to sudo.  This is where -E is needed.

```
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
wget -c https://dev.mysql.com/get/${MYSQL_8_file}
sudo -E dpkg -i ${MYSQL_8_file}
sudo apt update
sudo -E apt install -y mysql-server
```

Enjoy.

Comment: Here's another way to install mysql 8 without prompts. Took me forever to find this: https://gist.github.com/soubrunorocha/ec30b7704d737a1797b0281e97967834